# nginx proxying on websocket does not work (socket.io library)

Tags: node.js, ssl, websocket, socket.io, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm making an application based on WebSockets. Using the library socket.io . I use a self-signed certificate to configure HTTPS.

**For some reason, the proxying of the websocket connection does not work**, although the API proxying goes fine. Proxying goes from the NGINX container to the application container.

Below is the nginx config code:

```
user nginx;

worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        server_name x.x.x.x;

        location ~ ^/(api|socket\.io)/ {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass https://172.17.0.1:8443;
        }

        location / {
            index index.htm index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name x.x.x.x;

        return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Below is a part of the server code:

```
const { createServer } = require('https');
const { Server: WebSocketServer } = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/nginx-selfsigned.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt'),
  requestCert: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
};

const app = express();
const server = createServer(options, app);
const wss = new WebSocketServer(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: ['https://x.x.x.x', 'https://x.x.x.x:x:443']
  },
});

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['https://x.x.x.x', 'https://x.x.x.x:x:443'],
  })
);
```

Below is a request from the client to websocket:

`const socket = connect('https://x.x.x.x', { rejectUnauthorized: false });`

**As a result, the query below shows timed out**

`https x.x.x.x socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OjFL9C1`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a trailing slash (/) to the end of the proxy address can indeed be a potential issue, and it should be configured correctly to avoid conflicts with other paths. For example:

If you're using `/socket.io/` as the proxy path, the `proxy_pass` address should be like `https://172.17.0.1:8443/socket.io/`.

Making this adjustment, as shown below:

```
location ~ ^/(api|socket\.io)/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass https://172.17.0.1:8443/;
}
```

If your path is `/socket.io/`, this change may resolve your specific issue. Also, make sure that all other proxy and security settings are configured correctly.